# Regular expression to validate numbers separated by commas or dashes

Tags: c#, regex

It should validate something like this

```
12,14,15,18-20,23,50-130
```

I think of this:

```
^(?:\\d[,] | \\d[-])$ // or ^(?:\\d[,] | \\d[-] *)$ ??
```

**EDIT**
It should work for

```
12,  15
11,13, 14,18, 51-52
```

It should't work for

```
w,12
12,15d
14,,18
14--20
12,12-
-12,13
,12
12,
13-,
-,13
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: And what shouldn't be valid? And where are more examples of both valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: This should validate your given string: `12,14,15,18-20,23,50-130` ;-) With any question like this you have to not give an example but describe the rules you are trying to achieve. For any given example (or even group of examples) it is possible to come up with a rule that matches the examples but is not correct because there are things not listed that don't correctly match. Regular expressions are used to express rules and without knowing those rules you can't create a good regex.

Comment: Now why was this question closed? Because it doesn't contain an explicit "What am I doing wrong?"? The question contains both positive and negative examples and the OP's own attempt. That is a lot more than many other regex questions seem to contain. I would almost say that this is a comparably good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, use a verbatim string to avoid double-backslashes. And then this might do for you:

```
@"^\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?\s*(?:,\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?\s*)*$"
```

That would be a number, optionally followed by hyphen-number. And then an arbitrary amount of `,`, whitespace and the beginning pattern again.

Comment: i guess `5465,5-45-56` should match

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It how come? To me this looks like an enumeration of number-ranges (like the "Pages" field in a print dialog).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
@"^\s*\d+(\s*[,-]\s*\d+)*\s*$"
```

Comment: Then you should note that this allows multiple hyphens without commas in between ;)

Comment: @m.buettner may be..but op never said about that..:O

Comment: which is why I don't say your solution is wrong. But it is worthing pointing it out to the OP, don't you think?